# Donation authorization not possible?

Tags: paypal

I am using HTML variables for PayPal Standard for my donation page. According to [this page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/#capture-a-single-authorization), it should be possible to set paymentaction=authorization

However, testing says otherwise. The transaction is shown as a completed donation on the recipient account instead of a a pending authorization:

[image]

Here are my html variables:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Donation</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="donateForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="neil@example.com">
            <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
            <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/ipn.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/return.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="image_url" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="N/A">
            <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="authorization">
            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25">
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
            <input type="submit" value="Donate later!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?